# How do I stop rails from regenerating routes on every request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, routes

I am working on a pretty large rails project with a lot of routes. If rails is in development mode the app runs extremely slowly because it has to generate the routes repeatedly. I've tested this a couple of times by removing most of the routes and our app is nearly instant in bringing up our pages rather than the 10 or so seconds it usually takes. What I'm trying to find out is how I can stop rails from regenerating the routes on every request when in development mode. Is there a way to cache it or just stop it from regenerating?

Comment: How many routes are we talking about here? 10 seconds is a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise it, but set cache_classes to true in your config.  You'll have to restart the server every time you want to test a code change though.

Comment: yeah that's eve worse because I'd get hit with the time it takes to start up each time. Is there a way to profile how long it takes to load each of my classes and plugins that are getting reloaded?

Comment: Rails 3 does provide performance tests, which write profile results to the tmp/ directory.  I've never tried them, but it may be worth a look.

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?  1.9 is quite a bit faster than 1.8, apparently.  If you're getting hit on performance issues in pure ruby code as opposed to at the DB level, it might be worth looking at such things.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get anywhere with this?

I'm a little late to the party, and I don't have a direct answer for stopping the regeneration of routes, but would you accept speeding up other parts of the development environment as a compromise? If so, it's worth checking out the [Rails Development Boost](https://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost) gem. I've had some great speed increases from there.